# Spanish characters not properly displayed when converting .pdf to .txt using ghostscript

Tags: pdf, utf-8, character-encoding, ghostscript

I am trying to convert a pdf file with Spanish text into a .txt file using ghostscript on a Mac. Everything works well except the spanish - specific characters (e.g. í, ó) are not displayed properly (e.g. í appears as "¿≠"). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is a working example. Place the following text in the example.pdf file:

Este planeta además posee el día más largo del sistema solar: 243 días terrestres, y su movimiento es dextrógiro, es decir, gira en el sentido de las manecillas del reloj, contrario al movimiento de los otros planetas. Por ello, en un día venusiano el Sol sale por el oeste y se oculta por el este.

Then run

```
gs -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o output.txt example.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'example' is entirely insufficient, since you have not supplied an actual PDF file. If I create the PDF file myself it will not be the same as yours. In particular it may contain a ToUnicode CMap, which yours may not.

In the absence of a ToUnicode CMap any consumer has to guess at what the character codes represent (they may not represent any language encoding at all), and so you will not get the text you expect.

So its vitally important to supply an actual example file, not instructions on creating one.

You also haven't said which version of Ghostscript you are using.